# Retrofit unable to form proper PATCH request

Tags: android, retrofit2

The below curl is working properly on terminal

```
curl -X PATCH "https://nbk.synctactic.ai/meta/21/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "X-CSRFToken: 0S2DZHsLQGg0WGkoZcDgimrSzek7oCkvvKFt8jliJXYXbQay0vArsEt8Fnm56beg" -d {"dict":"{  "groups ": [ {  "id ":  "456c5d2a-8b30-49c2-b497-cd552ed2167e ",  "area ": 0,  "name ":  "Living Room ",  "carpet_area ": null }, {  "id ":  "01c7772c-664f-4477-92fa-823326725ca2 ",  "area ": 0,  "name ":  "Entrance ",  "carpet_area ": null } ],  "dimensions ": [ {  "x1 ": 101,  "x2 ": 102,  "y1 ": 3,  "y2 ": 49,  "uid ":  "19192f01-8447-4ba3-9de7-6961b415718f ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 102,  "x2 ": 36,  "y1 ": 49,  "y2 ": 51,  "uid ":  "18439cc6-3044-4b62-a7f7-6f36f98be0d7 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 36,  "x2 ": 37,  "y1 ": 51,  "y2 ": 423,  "uid ":  "7e803d94-c63a-4e79-b609-633605c12fd7 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 37,  "x2 ": 823,  "y1 ": 423,  "y2 ": 421,  "uid ":  "6a020939-b482-467a-a939-6eb9e62b30d1 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 823,  "x2 ": 819,  "y1 ": 421,  "y2 ": 46,  "uid ":  "cc007b1a-6276-454d-83f3-52fa5f2ccafa ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 819,  "x2 ": 564,  "y1 ": 46,  "y2 ": 45,  "uid ":  "68e76972-083b-4fa6-bd31-823872b00a4e ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 564,  "x2 ": 565,  "y1 ": 45,  "y2 ": 85,  "uid ":  "82322b82-890e-49fb-8d54-acb82ba5092e ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 565,  "x2 ": 295,  "y1 ": 85,  "y2 ": 80,  "uid ":  "b563fa5e-9ba6-44ed-b91e-c37453948ece ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 295,  "x2 ": 297,  "y1 ": 80,  "y2 ": 0,  "uid ":  "ccbb176f-bb9c-40a4-959c-3ac20861b4b6 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "EXTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 40,  "x2 ": 315,  "y1 ": 233,  "y2 ": 236,  "uid ":  "07aa961b-38c0-4dfc-9a60-05550a1e8a66 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 315,  "x2 ": 313,  "y1 ": 236,  "y2 ": 300,  "uid ":  "0afee208-3d03-4469-94de-9d8480acce1a ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 313,  "x2 ": 819,  "y1 ": 300,  "y2 ": 300,  "uid ":  "cfc01d0a-c225-42da-9403-c438643858e4 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 39,  "x2 ": 189,  "y1 ": 273,  "y2 ": 277,  "uid ":  "54f6edb8-2baa-4a4c-92f8-f41a7729a138 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 189,  "x2 ": 185,  "y1 ": 277,  "y2 ": 387,  "uid ":  "3106a28d-1655-4bc1-9c42-09947c196174 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 185,  "x2 ": 314,  "y1 ": 387,  "y2 ": 386,  "uid ":  "dc570951-34ae-4636-9107-3fad463a67f2 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 314,  "x2 ": 314,  "y1 ": 386,  "y2 ": 420,  "uid ":  "a829e233-2940-45b5-80c1-3b28cbbaad51 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 164,  "x2 ": 166,  "y1 ": 416,  "y2 ": 382,  "uid ":  "55c2c9c3-054f-49d1-afd7-7869c989679f ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 166,  "x2 ": 183,  "y1 ": 382,  "y2 ": 383,  "uid ":  "4d96f2d7-999b-48ae-a89a-c584e13f642e ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 309,  "x2 ": 311,  "y1 ": 86,  "y2 ": 235,  "uid ":  "78216011-1e47-4bfe-9232-cf5d9dc1b7f0 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 308,  "x2 ": 310,  "y1 ": 299,  "y2 ": 343,  "aid ":  "4d440b7a-3726-4c58-a3c9-30e8b78af00a ",  "uid ":  "eeb6507e-7d60-4d41-b341-b53ead40c123 ",  "type ":  "WALL ",  "sub_type ":  "INTERIOR " }, {  "x1 ": 687,  "x2 ": 687,  "y1 ": 50,  "y2 ": 296,  "gid ":  "456c5d2a-8b30-49c2-b497-cd552ed2167e ",  "uid ":  "f83efbe9-de9e-4006-931a-b1e802f12792 ",  "name ":  "L Breadth ",  "type ":  "MEASURE ",  "sub_type ":  "CARPET " }, {  "x1 ": 314,  "x2 ": 816,  "y1 ": 180,  "y2 ": 181,  "gid ":  "456c5d2a-8b30-49c2-b497-cd552ed2167e ",  "uid ":  "7c9e9e03-04f6-4402-a54b-789e86bc6b05 ",  "name ":  "L Length ",  "type ":  "MEASURE ",  "sub_type ":  "CARPET " }, {  "x1 ": 303,  "x2 ": 566,  "y1 ": 358,  "y2 ": 358,  "aid ":  "4d440b7a-3726-4c58-a3c9-30e8b78af00a ",  "uid ":  "1e8253e9-71a6-4892-a92a-67d5e7ed371e ",  "name ":  "E Wall Depth ",  "type ":  "MEASURE ",  "sub_type ":  "BUILDUP " }, {  "x1 ": 322,  "x2 ": 553,  "y1 ": 330,  "y2 ": 328,  "aid ":  "4d440b7a-3726-4c58-a3c9-30e8b78af00a ",  "gid ":  "01c7772c-664f-4477-92fa-823326725ca2 ",  "uid ":  "480d3d75-6e4d-4206-9081-b1fa11081e20 ",  "name ":  "E Length ",  "type ":  "MEASURE ",  "sub_type ":  "CARPET " }, {  "x1 ": 432,  "x2 ": 431,  "y1 ": 303,  "y2 ": 418,  "gid ":  "01c7772c-664f-4477-92fa-823326725ca2 ",  "uid ":  "c044eef5-7303-493b-aa30-80f75f8f864b ",  "name ":  "E Breadth ",  "type ":  "MEASURE ",  "sub_type ":  "CARPET " } ],  "associations ": [ {  "id ":  "4d440b7a-3726-4c58-a3c9-30e8b78af00a ",  "wall_depth ": 0 } ],  "uploadedImage ":  "data:image/png;base64,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 " }"}


@Multipart
@PATCH("/meta/{metaId}")
fun publishMap(@Header("Authorization") token: String, @Path("metaId") metaId: Int, @Part("dict") mapData:NemmadiMapData): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Comment: When you use tools like Charles Proxy to inspect the difference between the two, what do you see? Note that your Retrofit is lacking the `accept` and `X-CSRFToken` header values.

Comment: @CommonsWare wow sir ! Thank you for teaching me android. I am following you since 2011 !! Busy coder guide is amazing !! learned alot.. I remember you did a HSV wheel tutorial and I left a comment there !! [https://blog.stylingandroid.com/colour-wheel-part-2/]

Comment: and I will follow your advice, I think "Accept" is missing

Comment: "I remember you did a HSV wheel tutorial and I left a comment there" -- thanks! But, that was Mark Allison. We are very similar: same first name, similar glasses, similar hairlines, etc. He is incrementally more British, though. :-) But, getting back to your problem, seeing exactly what you are sending (OkHttp interceptor plugin, Charles Proxy, etc.) may help in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: oops ! I am so sorry for confusing with "The Mark Allison" !! Actually I am really excited to get a response from you. Actually you guys are giants in Android developer community and you guys have shaped many developer careers, including mine.. 
For my problem I used "https://github.com/mrmike/Ok2Curl" curl interceptor from here, but after adding Accept header, I got to know root problem was Django server was expecting URL to end with a "/" and I was getting StreamClosedException